# "I was an intern during / for 2 months"?

Tags: prepositions

On my resume I want to say that I was an intern then an employee in the position description:

> 'Intern for/during 2 months then employee'

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Many people who speak English as a second or third language tend to use **during** incorrectly when **for** is required.

You were **an intern for two months; then you were an employee**.